# text box value view as url in ext js 3

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have ExtJs text box. I want to view  text box value as URL. but url view as pain text. I want to view url inside the text box. my text filed is below

```
MyTextField3Ui = Ext.extend(Ext.form.TextField, {
    fieldLabel: 'Web Site',
    anchor: '100%',
    boxMaxWidth: 500,
    readOnly: true,
    id: 'website',
    initComponent: function() {
        MyTextField3Ui.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    }
});
```

I'm very new to ExtJs sorry for ask every small question. please help to me. Thankx

Comment: What do you mean by "view url"?

Comment: text box value want to be <a href="google.com">google.com</a> but now that only google('text')

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to define a widget from Ext.BoxComponent instead of Ext.form.TextField
and register some xtype like this.
 `Ext.reg('hreffield', "extended class name will go here");`
and into extended class define a property
 `defaultAutoCreate : {tag: "div"/"text" whatever you like},`
This will allow you to change.

usage will be

```
xtype: "hreffield",
id: "myid",
fieldLabel: "link",
width: 200,
tabIndex: 1,
value: "google.com"
```

Comment: i feel this is ok for static data but dynamically url how to set in the form. I have Store(`this.pstore = new Ext.data.JsonStore 
  ({
     idProperty: 'ID',
     autoLoad: true,
     mode: 'remote',
     url: url.com,
     keys:['ID'],
     fields: 
     ['WEBSITE',]
   });` ) i want to print this `WEBSITE` as url when click on the URL that Open in the new window

Comment: Value is not static. I am getting value from database in ajax call and then displaying in my form. In your case you always can get value from this.pstore.data.items[i] and assign it while creating form items.